# Need to combine consumable and non-reniewing subscription in one purchase

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I need to combine two types of the app-purchases in one item -- for example my purchase should be:

```
5 bananas / 6 months
```

So I can buy 5 bananas in my app, but I can eat/use them only for 6 months.

How can I implement this? Is it a normal usage of the purchases? Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. It seems like you will have to pick one of the two because your plan seems to violate some of Apple's guidelines.

According to [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/CreatingInAppPurchaseProducts.html):

> Because a non-renewing subscription requires a user to renew each time the subscription ends, your app must contain code that recognizes when the subscription is due to expire and prompt the user to purchase a new subscription.

So if your consumable cannot extended then it will be rejected.

Additionally, consumables

> are used one time

You cannot allow it to expire before it is used.